# How do I write a code that produces a table of a party cost based on seven values?

Tags: php, user-input

PHP – How do I write a code that produces a table of a party cost based on 7 values?

So for example, if min is  and max is 60 and cost1 is 5, cost2 is 10, cost3 is 15, cost4 is 20 and cost5 is 25

Comment: You are most likely looking for php arrays if you wanna hardcode the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start.

```
//the (int) changes the input to an integer, which will help prevent code injection.
//$_GET takes variables from the URL string, like http://google.com?min=30&max=60
//$_POST takes variables from a form on the page that then gets submitted <input type="text" name="min" value="30" />
$min = (int) $_GET['min'];
$max = (int) $_GET['max'];

$costs = array(
  '5',
  '10',
  '15',
  '20',
  '25',
);

echo '<table>';

for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++)
{
    //if the number is divisible by 5, show it in the table
    if($i % 5 === 0)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';

        foreach($costs as $cost)
        {
            echo '<td>' . $cost . '<br>' . $cost * $i . '</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }
 }

echo '</table>';
```

The resulting table will be:

30  150 300 450 600 750

35  175 350 525 700 875

etc... up to and including 60.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question. For the min and max,how do i make the variable min and max store a user input. Because I have a html page that allows the user to input and submit their values for min and max.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer. Trying to get some points on here :)

Comment: Where would you like the cost to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Just updated the code above to make sure the min & max values are defined :

```
<?php
//Added an other line to check if min & max values are defined
//the (int) changes the input to an integer, which will help prevent code injection.
//$_GET takes variables from the URL string, like http://localhost/test.php?min=30&max=60
//$_POST takes variables from a form on the page that then gets submitted <input type="text" name="min" value="30" />
if(isset($_GET['max']) && isset($_GET['min'])){
$min = (int) $_GET['min'];
$max = (int) $_GET['max'];

$costs = array(
  '5',
  '10',
  '15',
  '20',
  '25',
);

echo '<table>';

for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++)
{
    //if the number is divisible by 5, show it in the table
    if($i % 5 === 0)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';

        foreach($costs as $cost)
        {
            echo '<td>' . $cost * $i . '</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }
 }

echo '</table>';
}else echo "Please define the min & max values";
?>
```